# Touchstart event doesn't works in Windows Phone with Cordova/Phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have an app that have problems with touchstart events in Windows Phone. The application works correctly in Android, iOS and Blackberry, the problem is Windows Phone.

I have, for example, a piece of code:

```
<div class="page">    

<div class='divTest' id="divTest">HELLO</div>


</div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

     $('.divTest').on('touchstart', function () {
        alert('works"'');

    });

    var class_test = $('#divTest').attr("class");
    console.log(class_test);
});
</script>
```

JQuery works because in console show the class of "divTest" and other functions works well but not with event touchstart . I tried with differents forms but never show the alert.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks.